# Interaction with a matSuffix mat-checkbox in a mat-form-field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-event-emitter

I have an input in my `mat-form-field` that has a `mat-checkbox` in `matSuffix`.

INFO: *The input will be constantly disabled*.

```
<mat-form-field class="pointer" (click)="...">
  <mat-label>TEST ...</mat-label>
  <input matInput class="pointer" type="text" disabled>
  <mat-checkbox matSuffix color="accent" class="ml-4"></mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

I wish I could interact with the `mat-checkbox` without necessarily clicking on it directly,
but on the global `mat-form-field`.

**If I click here:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

I suppose that an event `(click)` on the `mat-form-field` would be necessary, but I do not know how to proceed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand well what you need, but i think that's it:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="100" class="pointer" (click)="disabled=!disabled">
 <mat-label>My label</mat-label>
  <input matInput class="pointer" type="text"  >
 <mat-checkbox matSuffix color="accent" [checked]="disabled" class="ml-4"></mat- 
 checkbox>
```

**TS**

```
disabled=false;
```

Comment: Or if you want disable you can use [disabled] instead of [checked]

Comment: Thank you @Leandro

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [disabled] attribute like this :

```
<mat-checkbox matSuffix color="accent" class="ml-4" [disabled]="yourBoolean"></mat-checkbox>
```

**'yourBoolean'** is a variable who can be initialized to false. At any time, you can change the value of this boolean somewhere else in your code and the checkbox will activate or deactivate dynamically